# Matlab: How to implement a bandpass filter to isolate harmonic with 0 gain at this frequency?

Tags: matlab, filters, bandpass

I want to isolate the harmonic at 440Hz and I need to design a filter with zero gain at 440Hz.
I tried this with matlab:

```
bandpass(ym, [2*pi*1*440/Fm-0.005, 2*pi*1*440/Fm+0.005], 2*pi);
```

However when I plotted the DFT i noticed larges values in y - axis (which means gain I guess). I cannot find in the documentation of `bandpass` how to controlt the gain.

Comment: What's the sampling frequency?

Comment: *// filter with zero gain at 440Hz//* ---- Do you mean $|H(440 \text{Hz})|=0$  or do you mean 0 dB?   The first is a notch filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple Butterworth filter (*I'm assuming a sampling frequency of $48 \texttt{Hz}$*). It can be implemented with 2 biquads:

```
fs = 48e3; % sampling frequency
f1 = 439;  % fpass 1
f2 = 441;  % fpass 2

[z,p,k] = butter(2, [2*f1/fs 2*f2/fs], 'bandpass');
sos = zp2sos(z,p,k);

[h, f] = freqz(sos,2^16,fs);

figure
subplot 211
yyaxis left
plot(f/1000, 10*log10(abs(h)));
grid on
ylabel('Magnitude (Hz)')
yyaxis right
ylabel('Phase (degrees)')
plot(f/1000, 180/pi*angle(h));
xlabel('frequency (kHz)')

subplot 212
yyaxis left
plot(f, 10*log10(abs(h)));
grid on
ylabel('Magnitude (Hz)')
yyaxis right
ylabel('Phase (degrees)')
plot(f, 180/pi*angle(h));
xlabel('frequency (Hz)')
xlim([380, 500])
```

[image]

You can of course increase the order to fit your specs, this is just an example of how to use some of the appropriate Matlab functions.

Comment: Do you know any recommended way to aply this filter to a signal? Because I always used the syntax with a, b and now the description is [z, p]

Comment: In Matlab, the [sosfilt](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sosfilt.html) function implements the filter.

Comment: for some reason when I plot my filter , gain is non-zero , does the number of samples 2^16 matter?

Comment: Well how do you plot your filter? The 2^16 Interpolates the spectrum, which is needed especially at lower frequencies. But it doesn’t change your filter.